# how to use DISTINCT properly to display only one item per user_id

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

Now, before I ask this...let me say I already searched for like ever and tried several things which just don't seem to work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have a website where users (with different "owner_id") can list one or multiple products. On one special page, I want to display only one product per "owner_id", which should be the most recent one.

I tried the DISTINCT query but for some reason it still returns all the products. What am I doing wrong? Here it is:

```
$sql_select_recent_items = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT owner_id, start_time, name, price, owner_id 
    FROM db_products 
    FORCE INDEX (products_start_time)
    WHERE closed=0 AND active=1 AND approved=1 AND deleted=0 AND creation_in_progress=0 
    ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

I also tried:

```
$sql_select_recent_items = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(owner_id), start_time, name, price, owner_id 
    FROM db_products 
    FORCE INDEX (products_start_time)
    WHERE closed=0 AND active=1 AND approved=1 AND deleted=0 AND creation_in_progress=0 
    ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

Both of the above don't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? I want to display just the most recent item (ORDER BY start_time DESC) and just limited to 1 item per "owner_id".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(owner_id), start_time, name, price
FROM db_products 
WHERE closed=0 AND active=1 AND approved=1 AND deleted=0 AND creation_in_progress=0 
group by owner_id
ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

Comment: That ALMOST seems to work! But strangely, it displays the oldest (by start_time) rather than the newest. I assume it could be because the GROUP by owner_id happens before the ORDER BY start_time?

Comment: I tried putting the GROUP after the ORDER but that returns a mySQL error.

Comment: No not after order by, see the above query and try it.

Comment: If you're doing DISTINCT on owner_id then you don't need the group - or the other way around.

Comment: I tried the exact query above, but it doesn't display the latest one, but the oldest one, however only 1 per owner_id, that is correct. I also tried without the GROUP but then it shows all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
SELECT owner_id, MIN(start_time), name, price
FROM db_products 
WHERE closed=0 AND active=1 AND approved=1 AND deleted=0 AND creation_in_progress=0 
GROUP BY owner_id
```

You can add `ORDER BY start_time DESC` if you want the final list (owner_id, start_id, name, price) to be sorted by start_id.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately :( As I'm trying to get only 1 result per owner_id

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I needed to do ORDER BY before the GROUP BY, which normally isn't possible. The solution to the problem can be found here:

http://arfeen.net/2012/10/mysql-use-of-group-after-order-by/